# Neo4j embedded DROP INDEX throws odd error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

## Setup

```
CREATE INDEX index_2384723 IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:Movie) ON (n.title)
```

## Run

```
call db.indexes() yield name, labelsOrTypes
where labelsOrTypes = ["Movie"]
DROP INDEX name IF EXISTS
RETURN name
```

## Expectation

Index with name index_2384723 to be dropped
and a return value:

`index_2384723`

## Reality

```
Invalid input 'R': expected 'e/E' (line 3, column 2 (offset: 77))
"DROP INDEX name IF EXISTS"
  ^
```

But why? Is this a neo4j cypher parsing bug or is the error on my side?
I dont get it...

The standalone queries work

```
call db.indexes() yield name, labelsOrTypes
where labelsOrTypes = ["Movie"]
RETURN name
```

this works.
and

```
DROP INDEX index_2384723 IF EXISTS
```

this works too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the index using cypher.  The name returned by db.indexes() is the value string (or name) of the index rather than the index itself. You can delete it in below steps.

```
1. List the index (or indices) that you want to remove

   call db.indexes() yield name, labelsOrTypes 
   WITH name, labelsOrTypes where ANY (lbl in ['Movie',  'Person'] WHERE lbl in labelsOrTypes)
   RETURN name, labelsOrTypes

2. Pick the index (or indices) that you want to delete and copy/paste in neo4j browser

   DROP INDEX index_2384723 IF EXISTS;
   DROP INDEX index_Person IF EXISTS;

 3. Execute and verify

   Removed 1 index, completed after 4 ms.
```

Comment: Yea, i know this works. But why does  the combined approach not work?
When calling `DROP INDEX index_2384723 IF EXISTS;` i provide the index name as a string as well.
In my view this is a bug or at least a shortcoming.
what is the reasoning behind this behaviour?

Comment: It is not allowed to run drop/create index on a query. You need to submit this as a new feature or enhancement to neo4j.

Comment: ok, so it is intentional. Do have any knowledge, on why ii would restrict such constructs? and the error message is really not helpful :)